# Is there an automated tool for making photo-mosaics (using images as pixels)?

Tags: graphics

I occasionally see portraits and other images which have been redrawn into an abstract form, where each pixel in the redrawn image is actually another, much smaller picture.

I am looking for a tool (or library) which can perform this type of transformation automatically. Does something like that exist?

Comment: You got a preferred language? :)

Comment: Is it something like a picture mosaic like this you are referring to ? http://www.bz-berlin.de/aktuell/berlinmosaik/

Comment: Nope. Any language will do, as long as the library is stable and works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of a [Photomosaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic). You can use [AndreaMosaic](http://www.andreaplanet.com/andreamosaic/). There is a [HowTo](http://www.engadget.com/2004/10/19/how-to-make-your-own-photo-mosaics/) here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any existing tool; but the general algorithm would be to look at each pixel in the source image, and from a pool of pictures select one to represent the picture. You would probably want select the image that has the most content of the pixel color. (So when you encounter a blue pixel, you select an image to represent it, that is mostly blue, and so on).